# Show a prime number exists between $n$ and $n!$

Tags: prime-numbers

All $n$ bigger than $2$ has $p$ (prime number) such that $p$ divides $n$.
Then a $p$ exists which divides $(n - 1)!$

With this, i have no idea how to show that $p$ is bigger than $n$ ($n < p < n!$).

Answer (score 1):

$(n-1)!$ doesn't work because its prime factors are all less than $n$.

Instead, look at $n!-1$ which is coprime to any numbers $k=2,3,\dots,n$. Thus a prime factor of $n!-1$ is larger than $n$ but less than $n!$.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bertrand Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) hence $(2n-2)<n!$ you get your proof